# Synonyms: [site-deployment] or [website-deployment]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

We have two tags that appear to mean the same thing:

- [website-deployment](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website-deployment) - 10 questions
- [site-deployment](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-deployment) - 35 questions

Making one of these a tag synonym of the other seems like a no-brainer to me.  Which tag should be the master?

Alternatively, we could create [deployment](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deployment) and make both the others point to it, since "site" and "website" seem pretty redundant here.

Comment: StackOverflow has [web-deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/web-deployment) (4500 questions) and [website-deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/website-deployment) (29 questions) - no synonyms. (As well as [deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/deployment) (24k questions)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that "site" and "website" are redundant, unless there's something besides a website that could be deployed and would generate an on-topic question here.

I would support both of them being merged into a new [deployment](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deployment) tag.

Comment: The "something besides a website that could be deployed and would generate an on-topic question here" is what I've been chewing on and I can't come up with anything.

Comment: gopher and/or gemini could be considered on topic or not. But are they then websites or sites? Is "web" attached to HTTP specially?

Comment: Or IPFS - interplanetary filesystem also dubbed as "Distributed web" but then deployment there might be difficult to define precisely as it is peer to peer by design.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Those are thoughtful examples. My opinion is that Gopher/Gemini/IPFS are web-like enough that a single `deployment` tag would work well as a catch-all, especially when a post is paired with additional disambiguating tags.